# layoutsxxxhdpi has difference in few of devices of android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I am new to android studio , i have set layout of xxxhdpi devices . Devices Pixel XL, Nexus 6, Nexus 6p have size(1440*2560) 560 dpi and their layouts are fine but Pixel XL 2 has size (1440*2880) 560 dpi layout is pushing downward , how to reduce difference for that?

Answer (score 0):

For keeping all these **‘screen resolution and density’** combinations simpler, Android wants us to consider them as DIP or DP units (Density Independent Pixels), which are corrected for density. For designing/development perspective, Android treats any device as its DP unit size instead of its actual pixel size. Android calculates DP size by using the following formula:

DP size of any device is (actual resolution/density conversion factor).
Density conversion factor for density buckets are as follows:

> **ldpi: 0.75
>
>   mdpi: 1.0 (base density)
>
>   hdpi: 1.5
>
>   xhdpi: 2.0
>
>   xxhdpi: 3.0
>
>   xxxhdpi: 4.0**

**Examples of resolution/density conversion to DP:**

> ldpi device of 240 X 320 px will be of 320 X 426.66 DP.
>   240 / 0.75 = 320 dp
>   320 / 0.75 = 426.66 dp
>
> xxhdpi device of 1080 x 1920 pixels (Samsung S4, S5) will be of 360 X 640 dp.**
>   1080 / 3 = 360 dp
>   1920 / 3 = 640 dp

follow this link, http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/